# Suppose. a∈R. Show that sup{r∈Q:r<a}=a.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a\in\mathbb R$. Show that $\sup\{r\in\mathbb Q\ :\ r<a\}=a$.

My attempt: $S:=\{r\in\mathbb Q, r<a\}$. From this, we can see that $S$ is certainly bounded
from above. And I tried to use a new point $b$ to show that $a$ is the Supremum but got stuck...

Comment: Suppose. a∈R. Show that sup{r∈Q:r<a}=a.

My attempt: 
S:={r∈Q:r<a}. From this, we can see that S is certainly bounded
from above. And I tried to use a new point b to show that a is the Supremum but got stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Show that $a$ is an upper bound for $S$
2. Show that if $b$ is an upper bound for $S$, then $a\le b$.

---

**Extra hint for $2$:**

> If $b$ is an upper bound for $S$ and $b<a$, then $b \in S$. Can you use the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ to find an element of $S$ that is larger than $b$? Can this happen if $b$ is an upper bound?

Comment: Guys so many advices , I'm confused with what to do... I'm a beginner which one uses basic axioms?

Comment: All of the answers give you the same argument, and all are equally correct. You should mark as correct the answer that you found the most useful and clear.

Comment: Do you understand what to do now, or do you have any further issues?

Comment: I still do not understand... I understand to the part where I get a point where I show that a is an upper bound for S. But then how to show that b is greater than a. B can be anywhere right?

Comment: Have you looked at the extra hint (hover over it)?

Comment: Yes I understand when b Is less it is inside and not an upper bound. But after the signs are messy and do not understand what is written...

Comment: Now it's better, thanks!!!

Comment: Can you explain what you have?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$ where $a<b$, there is a rational number $r$ such that $a<r<b$.

Comment: by the denseness of
Q in R , we know that
if (a; b) are In R
with a < b, then exists an r that is rational and  a < r < b. So although we know
S is bounded and we can certainly povide many upper bounds... Is this the right direction?

Comment: Well, the takeaway is more along the lines of showing that $a$ is in fact that *least* upper bound of $\{r\in \mathbb{Q} \mid r<a\}$.  To see this, suppose that there were an upper bound of this set $b$ such that $b<a$.  Then you can use the denseness to arrive at a contradiction, showing that $a$ must in fact be the least upper bound.

Answer (score 3):

Let $E = \{ r\in\Bbb Q: r < a\}$.

1. $\forall r\in E \ \ \ r \le a \implies \sup E \le a $
2. Consider $\epsilon >0$. As $\Bbb Q$ is a dense set in $\Bbb R$, there is an
   $r\in \Bbb Q, \ \ \  a-\epsilon < r < a$. In particular, $r\in E$ and so $\sup E > r-\epsilon$.
3. This is true for every $\epsilon$, hence $\sup E \ge a$.

Comment: This is a very clear and concise answer! Thank you for your efforts!